# PHP SSL ciphers differences and comparison

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

There's a long list of SSL ciphers available in PHP via `openssl_get_cipher_methods()`:

[PHP SSL ciphers](https://pastebin.com/znF3YCzb)

What does the extension on each cipher specify? (e.g. cbc, gcm,...)

Which one of the listed ones should be used if the requirements are:

- Fastest (less secure) cipher?
- Best practice (secure) cipher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does the extension on each cipher specify? (e.g. cbc, gcm,...)

The extension is [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). Most of the ciphers are *block ciphers* encrypting a single block of data. There are several ways how to securely encrypt larger data (multiple blocks). The extension indicates how multiple blocks are handled.

> Fastest (less secure) cipher? 
>   Best practice (secure) cipher?

Do not use *ecb* mode until you have no other option (less secure).

Almost all simple modes (cbc, ofb, ...) are equivalent in speed, in theory you may use any of them. It is more important you don't use any unsecure (obsolete cipher), such as DES.

The most used I see is the CBC mode, I assume it's because almost all tools support the mode. Many people don't realize the CBC cipher is [malleable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleability_(cryptography)), so some sort of integrity check is necessary.

The *gcm* mode includes the integrity check information, so in theory it is slower, but the cipher executes the integrity check for you.